# Is this question on topic?

Tags: soporte, ámbito

Is any portion of what follows on topic?

> I'm looking for either an answer or a reference.  I have the impression that US Spanish-speakers are distributed differently now than previously.  I think the distribution used to be primarily in certain specific major population centers and certain regions, whereas now there is more peppering all around the country.  I'm interested to know if there is data about this, and if it backs up my conjecture.  Also, I wonder how linear or nonlinear this spreading out transformation might have occurred, and what's behind it.

Comment: I think it is quite on topic to ask where and how are Spanish speakers distributed throughout any area. In this specific case of US I assume there will be quite a lot of data and then elements to think about, as well as explanations on the evolution of the areas. To me, it can be a great question.

Comment: @fedorqui just to open the possibility of a little debate, wouln't it be more of a question about demography? Demography is the statistical study of populations and the spatial or temporal changes in them. The fact that the OP is trying to study the population according to the language they speak (which in this case just happens to be a variant of Spanish) may not render the question on topic here, as more knowledge is needed about demography rather than about our language. Could it be a "Spanish Language meets [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/)" question?

Comment: Cc: @walen. ^^^

Comment: @Charlie - related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315956/what-is-the-ideal-se-site-to-ask-about-population-growth-and-demographics-in-gen

Comment: @walen - I guess I'm interested in two things -- 1, how the total number of Spanish speakers has changed over time in the US, and 2, how the distribution within the US has changed over time.  For 1, there are births, immigration, and intermarriage, adding to the numbers, and decreases would come from deaths, departures including deportation, and language loss through the generations.  I'm not sure how a scholar could even get good numbers.

Comment: @Charlie disculpa, no contesté. Coincido con lo expuesto por walen.

Comment: @fedorqui yo era por ver si podía haber debate, pero si a vosotros os parece bien, a mí también. :-)

Comment: @Charlie me pillas en unos días flojo. Cuando la salud repunte espero volver con el cuchillo entre los dientes y listo para debatir :P

Comment: @fedorqui no tenía ni idea, espero que no sea nada grave y que mejores pronto!